# Lightning Component: Css class for uiOutputText

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I'd like to figure out why my component's CSS is not applied. I have a very simple
**ui:outputtext**:

```
<ui:outputtext value="My Text" class="boldtext" />
```

And the following CSS:

```
.THIS .boldtext {
    font-weight: bold; 
}
```

The **ui:outputtext** renders to:

```
<span class="uiOutputText cMyComponent boldtext" dir="ltr" data-aura-rendered-by="108:1;0" data-aura-class="uiOutputText cMyComponent ">My Text</span>
```

But unfortunately, component's text is not bold and I didn't see my component's CSS defined anywhere. Did I miss anything important?

P.S.: My component is related to the object:

```
 implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId"
```

Does that matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.When you do not leave space between THIS and class Name denotes its top level element .This should work for you

```
.THIS.boldtext {
 font-weight: bold; 
}
```

2.When you leave space between THIS and class Name denotes its decendent or nested element has its style .

```
.THIS .boldtext {
   font-weight: bold; 
}
```

In your case its toplevel element so do not leave the space .

Comment: Isn't this nuance the same as it is with any CSS selector sans Lightning? I am not a CSS guru but I thought that was how it worked...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036156/whats-the-difference-between-css-classes-foo-bar-without-space-and-foo-bar

Comment: @Eric you are right and i am not CSS guru as well .But what confuses me always is THIS notation and then each component has ability to do its own CSS .

Comment: Yea, just trying to learn through clarity.....I think of THIS just like the $(this) jQuery selector. Its a starting point and is a selector like any other. I may be thinking of it wrong but it helps *me* to keep a handle on it lol

Comment: Ha :) .Nice analogy and yes its like any other selector and i imagine THIS as the main container of the component :)