# Can't modify the css of lightning:select

Tags: css, lightningselect

I added a new Lightning component.

All is good (controller, helper, apex controller...), but the position of Lightning:select doesn't change. I don't know why. I want to center the lightning:select in my page and also modify the width of the option.

There's my script:

The component:

```
<lightning:select name="Famille" label="{!$Label.c.RD_Categorie}" value="
        {!v.famille}" class="modifTailleListe">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item">
        <option value="{!item.key}" text="{!item.value}"></option>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

There's my CSS:

```
.THIS .modifTailleListe {
    margin:auto;
    width:50%;
}
```

I tried also:

```
.THIS .slds-form-element .modifTailleListe {
    margin:auto;
    width:50%;
}
```

And it  didn't work.

In fact the problem (it's very stange), in the browser, the css of .modifTailleListe isn't display.

I'm seeing only

```
.slds-form-element {
    position: relative;
}
```

And I want to replace it by my css script.

I find this behavior strange.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this query : [Ligtning Component: Css class for uiOutputText](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137603/ligtning-component-css-class-for-uioutputtext) (our website :D)

In fact, I must leave the space between .THIS and the class name:

So, it's:
.THIS.modifTailleListe {
    margin:auto;
    width:50%;
}

And it works.

Thank you a lot.

Have a good afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it didn't worked.
This is the result (see the image). 
When I added your script, it modified the position of the 2 first label and input, it didn't modify the position of the lightning:select.

There's all my script:

`

```
<div class="slds-form-element__group">
<div class="slds-form-element__row">
<div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-2 pavePourcentage">
<label class="slds-form-element__label" for="form-element-01">{!$Label.c.RD_Pourcentage}</label>
<input type="Double" id="form-element-01" class="slds-input valPourcentage" value="{!v.remisePourcentage}"/>
</div>
<div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-2 paveMontant">
<label class="slds-form-element__label" for="form-element-01">{!$Label.c.RD_Montant}</label>
<input type="Double" id="form-element-01" class="slds-input valMontant" value="{!v.remiseMontantDevise}"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</div>
</div>

<lightning:select name="Famille" label="{!$Label.c.RD_Categorie}" value="{!v.famille}" class="modifTailleListe">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item">
        <option value="{!item.key}" text="{!item.value}"></option>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

`

The css:

`.THIS .pavePourcentage{
    float:left;
}

.THIS .paveMontant {
    float:right;
}

.THIS .valPourcentage {
    width:30%;
    display:inherit;
}

.THIS .valMontant {
    width:30%;
    display:inherit;
}

.THIS .slds-form-element{
    margin:auto;
    width:50%;
 }`

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer, please edit your original post.

Answer (score -1):

try to put your CSS inside **.THIS .slds-form-element{**

```
    .THIS .slds-form-element{
margin:auto;
    width:50%;
 }
```